# creating a folder/uploading a file in amazon S3 bucket using API

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am a total newbie to amazon and java trying two things:

1. I am trying to create a folder in my Amazon S3 bucket that i have already created and have got the credentials for.
2. I am trying to upload a file to this bucket.

As per my understanding i can use putObjectRequest() method for acheiving both of my tasks.

```
PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file)
```

for uploading a file.

I am not sure if i should use this method

```
PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, InputStream input,
        ObjectMetadata metadata)
```

for just creating a folder. I am struggling with InputSteam and ObjectMetadata. I don't know what exactly is this for and how I can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file) to achive both task.

1, create S3 folder
With AWS S3 Java SDK , just add "/" at the end of the key name, it will create empty folder.

```
var folderKey =  key + "/"; //end the key name with "/"
```

Sample code:

```
final InputStream im = new InputStream() {
      @Override
      public int read() throws IOException {
        return -1;
      }
    };
    final ObjectMetadata om = new ObjectMetadata();
    om.setContentLength(0L);
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, objectName, im, om);
    s3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

2, Uploading file
Just similar, you can get input stream from your local file.

Answer (score 19):

You do not need to create a folder in Amazon S3. In fact, folders do not exist!

Rather, the **Key** (filename) contains the **full path and the object name**.

For example, if a file called `cat.jpg` is in the `animals` folder, then the Key (filename) is: `animals/cat.jpg`

Simply `Put` an object with that Key and the folder is automatically created. (Actually, this isn't true because there are no folders, but it's a nice simple way to imagine the concept.)

As to which function to use... always use the simplest one that meets your needs. Therefore, just use `PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file)`.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively you can use [[minio client]](https://github.com/minio/minio-java) java library

You can follow [MakeBucket.java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/examples/MakeBucket.java) example to create a bucket & [PutObject.java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/examples/PutObject.java) example to add an object.

Hope it help.